# Passing database credentials between applications

Tags: .net, oracle, authentication

I'm developing a lightweight .NET framework (for internal purposes) with single sign functionality. A primary application is first launched, which asks the user to log in. After that, the user is shown a list of applications to launch.

These secondary applications are standalone applications, but they need to use the same credentials to log in to the database (Oracle) as to those that were passed to the primary application.

Is there a secure way of implementing this? Either through passing information on the command line encrypted in some way, or the two applications communicating in one way or another (the primary application has access to the Process that the secondary applications are executed in).

Launching these applications differently would also be possible, if that offered more functionality (i.e. load the executable into the App domain and run it that way).

Comment: The secure way to implement it is to not have clients directly accessing the DB.  Have 2 tier app where a WCF service access the DB.

Comment: These are fairly heavy applications that each access different database domains. Putting all this into the primary application would create a massive application with a large number of dependencies. The aim is to make it so these applications can be modified/added individually.

Comment: For small intranet asp apps, I use active directory for credentials.  For single sign on with more bells/whistles, have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx

Comment: Since this is mostly concerned with Oracle login credentials, the usual SSO designs do not work since they work on the assumption that you control the login system. That's why I'm basically forced to use connection strings, or having access to the username/password in some way.